# HTML/CSS Navigation not pushing down: After responsive display not displaying full height and scroll

Tags: html, css, web

I have a navigation bar which does not scroll after display in responsive mode.
I will provide you with a link to my website: [WebSite Link with navigation bar example](http://imobilselect.forithost.com)

Just resize the window to a maximum of 500px and click the navigation to open menu.

Click the submenu's and you will see that it will not display all of the navigation content and also displaying over the website's content.
I want to make it show all its height and push down content also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the submenus are too long to be displayed, so the people who created the theme/template made these dropdown containers 200px high and enabled scrolling in them (you CAN scroll down in them). This is written in the following CSS rule:

```
.menu > ul > li > ul {
    position: relative;
    overflow: scroll;
    height: 200px !important;
}
```

You can take out the last part, which will show the fill length. However, this will go beyond the bottom of the screen and NOT scroll, so you'll be better off with the given situation. You can also change the pixel value in `height: 200px !important;` - this will make the submenus a bit higher, but that doesn't make it much better.

I would leave it as it is and maybe add an icon that makes it more obvious that the content of the dropdowns can be scrolled.

Comment: Thank you for your time, i did the height and overflow to scroll. But i want it to display the whole navigation and push content down. Because on a small screen mobile display the menu will not scroll but only the submenu on click and it will appear just half of the whole menu.

Comment: Your example isn't online anymore, so I can't talk about details, but in general you could deactivate that heigth and scroll for the submenus (with `overflow: visible` and no height) and set all surrounding containers to "overflow: visible. Then the body should be as high as necessary and it would also be the element that scrolls.

Comment: In my previous comment I meant to emphasize that also/especially `body` should get `overflow: visible` (actually `overflow-y: visible`).